# Converting stream to bool - how is it done in getline()

Tags: c++, stream, type-conversion, getline

I was wondering how it is possible that we can chain stream operations using the following piece of code:

```
while(getline(stream,string){
//do stuff
}
```

I've read multiple threads in the internet, on stackoverflow and many other sites. I've found streams use 2 conversions operators

```
operator void*() const; //c++98
explicit operator bool() const; //c++11
```

And while I can fully understand the c++11 conversion, I'm having trobule in understanding how it is possible that a pointer is being treated in a bool test.

[The reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/) says a nullptr is returned if something goes wrong and some other values when everything's ok.
Having all that knowledge I assume that it is fine then you perform if() test on a pointer.But what happens if I try so? My app crashes.

Could someone explain it to me, how a void* pointer is treated as true/false?

Comment: Zero is false. `NULL` is zero.

Comment: In order to figure out why your app crashes we'll need more information. Preferably a [mcve].

Comment: Treating a pointer as a boolean (with NULL being false and anything else being true) is just an unfortunate legacy from C. Your crash is caused by something else.

Comment: Indeed, you were right. My crash was caused by some allocation issue I've managed to fix.